# AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python

I'm really new to this whole thing, so excuse the maybe stupid question, but I am too stupid to find the answer myself.

I've got a list with links URLs and timestamps and want to shorten the URLs and save the result to a new file.
But running

```
file = open('history.csv','r')
clean = open('historyclean.csv','a')

for x in file:
    b = x.rsplit('/',1)
    b.pop()
        clean.append(b)
```

results in

```
    AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'append'
```

and I can't find out why.
I am using Python 2.7, if relevant

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `clean.write`, not `clean.append`. As the error states files have no append operation.